# Replace 2nd occurance of a special character after nth occurance of a delimiter from string,in unix/linux

Tags: string, unix

Here My question is,

Replace 2nd or all occurance of a special character after nth occurance of a delimiter from string,in unix/linux

or

Replace "Text Qualifier" character from data field in unix.

I have below string where '"'(Double Quote) should get replaced with space.

String:

```
"123"~"23"~"abc"~24.50~"descr :- nut size 12" & bolt size 12"1/2, Quantity=20"~"2013-03-13"
```

From above string, i want below output:

```
"123"~"23"~"abc"~24.50~"descr :- nut size 12  & bolt size 12 1/2, Quantity=20"~"2013-03-13"
```

I have replaced " double quote character with space character.

```
"descr :- nut size 12" & bolt size 12"1/2, Quantity=20"
```

&

```
"descr :- nut size 12  & bolt size 12 1/2, Quantity=20"
```

I want to identify such rows from file & would like to replace such text qualifier character from data in Unix/Linux.

Request you to provide your inputs, & thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would use plain `read` to get the fields and then modify the wished ones using `sed` or shell variable substitution mechanisms:

```
echo '"123"~"23"~"abc"~24.50~"descr :- nut size 12" & bolt size 12"1/2, Quantity=20"~"2013-03-13"' | {
  IFS='~' read a b c d e f
  printf "%s~%s~%s~%s~%s~%s" "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d" "$(sed 's/"/ /g' <<<$e)" "$f"
  # or:
  printf "%s~%s~%s~%s~%s~%s" "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d" "${e//\"/ }" "$f"
}
```

That `IFS` ("Internal Field Separator") is an internal variable telling the shell how to separate fields, e.g. when using `read`.  In our case using this tells the shell to use `~` as separator.  Prepending the assignment directly to the `read` command makes that assignment only for the duration of the `read` command.

Comment: This one's better than my idea. IFS is a special shell variable, maybe OP doesn't know.

Comment: Right.  Will add info about that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you work in the bash shell.

awk(awk) can help you split your input string at the right positions, using its "-F" option:

```
echo xyzabcdef | awk -Fb '{print $1}'
```

gives you "xyza", the the first string before the separator.

Then, the tr(1) utility can help you replace characters:

```
tr '"' ' '
```

will replace '"' with ' '. I hope this helps to get you in the right direction.

Comment: I am facing same kind of issue.. i want to replace such text qualifier characters from file. can someone please let me know way to achieve it??